# Request Failure Status Code 200 Status Text BADRESPONSE: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, cloudflare

I get the below error when I click on the ImageButton. It works without error when I run the application using visual studio. It also works without error in one machine. But it is giving this error only in another machine.

[image: Error]

I have deployed the same code on both machines. I have added logs in the button click event also, so it is failing before the button click event only and it is not throwing any exception also.

The only difference I can see is that in-browser console network windows I can see the POST call response returning HTML (webform content) in failed case but in passing case, it is returning JSON. So I am 100% sure that it is expecting JSON but it is getting HTML in place of in the response.

The only change I have done is added WCF service reference to the project and nothing else. and I am not calling the WCF method on my page.

So What is causing the issue? and how can I fix this issue?

My application web.config:

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://servername:9033/Services/ServiceName" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="ServiceName.IServiceXYZ" name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" />

<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
        <security mode="None">
            <transport sslProtocols="None" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

**Edit:** I have got the root cause of the issues, I have uninstalled the Cloudflare from the server, it's working as expected now.

So now my question is why Cloudflare is causing this issue? What can be the root cause and How to fix it? Are there any logs to check why is it failing?

Comment: What is there in html in failed case. Have you tried to create an html for that response and see in the browser what is there. Also you need to check the request parameter in both the cases in the browser. Are the browser version is same in both the cases?

Comment: Yes, everything same. I suspect it is due to WCF.

Comment: what the response html says in case of failure?

Comment: It is returning the the form as html

Comment: what is there in the html? can you read the html. may be it returning some error in form of html. can you post it in your question?

Comment: It’s not returning any errors

Comment: can you put the html in your question which you are getting in response.

Comment: @शेखर I have sent you mail on hishekhar1@gmail.com, please check

Comment: `ConfirmInflows.aspx` is this your current page from where you are calling the service?

Comment: @शेखर yes from this page